# How to like / dislike a video on Youtube via API (v3) without extended user permissions?

Tags: permissions, youtube-api

I´m building an application where users can like or dislike a video on youtube via the YouTube Data API (v3).

Question:
Is it possible to let users rate a video with read only authentication by youtube API?
I managed to do it with write access but I don´t think the users like to give me access to their whole YouTube account.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't an OAuth 2 scope that will allow for rating a video but not other "write" operations. Asking for the full `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` scope is required.